# Poisson Probability Problem in R

Tags: r, probability, poisson-distribution

I have a data frame with 2 columns x,f that correspond to :

x : A measurement of the number of mosquitos that enter the room in a minute.

f : The number of occurrences of each number of mosquitos per minute within the set.

```
library(tidyverse)
x = seq(0,14,1);x
f = c(8,32,89,134,170,170,145,103,65,36,17,7,3,1,1)
df = tibble(x,f);df
```

Given that the x in the data frame follows Poisson
distribution I have to calculate the lambda parameter :

```
> df%>%summarise(lambda = sum(x*f)/ sum(x))
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  lambda
   <dbl>
1  46.54


#or as.numeric

lam = as.numeric(df%>%summarise(lambda = sum(x*f)/ sum(x))) 
> lam
[1] 46.54286
```

and now I have to answer in 2 questions :

**1)** Find the probability that 40 mosquitos that will enter the room in 20 minutes.

**2)** Find the probability that the number of mosquitos that will enter the room in 5 minutes will be between 20 and 25.

How can I find these probabilities for question 1 and 2?

Comment: $46.54$ is totally implausible for the average rate, which clearly cannot exceed the maximum rate of $14$ and is likely to be closer to $5$; you have an error and should have summed the frequencies as in `df%>%summarise(lambda=sum(x*f)/sum(f))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your calculation of $\lambda$ is incorrect.  The variable `x` is the number of mosquitos entering the room per minute.  The $i^{th}$ entry in `f` is the number of occurrences of the observation `x[i]`.  So from what I understand, we see 0 mosquitos entering a room 8 times, 1 mosquito entering the room 32 times, and so on.

Hence, `f` are the weights of each of the `x`, and so $\lambda$ is estimated by

```r
> sum(y*f)/sum(f)
[1] 4.981651
```

So $\hat{\lambda} = 4.98$.

> 1. Find the probability that 40 mosquitos that will enter the room in 20 minutes.

The poisson distribution has the property that the sum of $n$ iid poisson random variables is also poisson distributed with rate parameter $n\lambda$.  Hence, the rate parameter for this question is $20 \hat{\lambda}$.

Using R,

```r
lam = sum(y*f)/sum(f)
dpois(40, 20*lam)
[1] 5.680858e-12
```

> 2. Find the probability that the number of mosquitos that will enter the room in 5 minutes will be between 20 and 25.

I'm interpreting this as $p(20 \leq x \leq 25)$.

For this question, our rate parameter is $5\hat{\lambda}$.  Using the cumulative mass function, $P$, we can compute this as

$$ P(25; 5\hat{\lambda}) - P(20; 5\hat{\lambda})$$

Where

In R

```r
> ppois(25, 5*lam) - ppois(19, 5*lam)
[1] 0.4227893
```

Comment: Don't you think this is a homework question? In which case it wasn't the best idea to solve the OP's homework for them.

Comment: @dipetkov When I was a student, I asked for help dozens of times on stack exchange. Often, I was given guided answers, but others I just got the answer right away.  Sometimes seeing the solution can help clarify the process.  I'm not advocating for always doing this, but I think once in a while it is OK to throw people a bone.

Comment: I actually think it's the OP's loss that you just gave them the answer.

Comment: @dipetkov Then that's OP's problem.  Learning from example is a legitimate strategy, and if OP doesn't want to use that and instead take the answer and run then I don't see why the onus should fall on the members of this community to rectify that.

Comment: Have you read the "Answering self-study questions" part of the [self-study wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)?

Comment: @dipetkov I have.  Those are *guidelines*, not requirements.  I am erring on the side of providing useful resource for posterity, leaving the responsibility to learn with OP.  If you have a suggestion for how to improve the answer, I'm willing to consider it, but I stand by my rationale for answering it outright.